# How do I autogenerate a list of urls for requests call?

Tags: python-3.x

Beginner here.

I am creating a web scraper, that will requests.get() multiple pages for instance in a search result.

I've made a list called pages, and then run a loop that requests.get() all the pages. Esentially I want a function that autogenerates a list of URLs but manipulates part of the URL every time it's repeated.

Almost like so

```
url_base = "www.page.com/page"
pnumber = 1
url = url_base + pnumber
```

But every time the loop is repeated 1 is added to pnumber to get a list like this:

```
pages = [
'www.page.com/page1'
'www.page.com/page2'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `range`

**Ex:**

```
url_base = "www.page.com/page{}"
for i in range(10):
    url = url_base.format(i)
    print(url)
```

**Output:**

```
www.page.com/page0
www.page.com/page1
www.page.com/page2
www.page.com/page3
www.page.com/page4
www.page.com/page5
www.page.com/page6
www.page.com/page7
www.page.com/page8
www.page.com/page9
```